# What size gas line do I need to run to my garage

Tags: garage, gas

I am looking to run about 50 feet of black steel gas line through a basement room, underground and out to my garage for a radiant heater. I'd like to put an underground junction in it so that I can hook up an outdoor LP grill.

1. is a 3/8" line large enough?
2. I have read that I can not have any joints covered up by a finished ceiling. Does that seem correct? (I'd have to get one long solid pipe to run the length of the room)
3. How deep would it have to be buried?
4. Where can I get an underground junction that I could turn off without digging up the line? Or does that seem unnecessary? I live in Minneapolis/Richfield MN.

I'm also open to better/simpler solutions.

Comment: If you have a bunch of questions, it's better to ask a bunch of questions.  Asking multiple questions in a single post, makes it difficult for folks to provide good informative answers.  Please consider splitting your post into multiple questions.

Answer (score 2):

Step one would be to check with your local inspection authority. **Gas work by non-licensed professionals is prohibited in many jurisdictions.**

If it's not prohibited, they may offer advice on material and installation requirements. You can also talk to the employees at a local gas supply store.

A good option for your project would be a direct burial flexible gas line, a.k.a. poly gas pipe. Such a line could be installed so that you have no buried fittings.

Whatever you bury, make sure you place a layer of AT LEAST 6 inches of sand over the line. You should also put a marker tape over the line. The marker tape and the sand serve as indicator to future diggers that something is buried below. Pea gravel below the line is a good idea so that any water that seeps in leaches away quickly and does not stay in contact with the line.

For an example of how to use the sand and marker tape, see the segment of [this video from Ask This Old House](http://video.pbs.org/video/2290183787/) where they install a blue stone patio. And here's a crude diagram:

[image]